# Excel doesn't recognize dates when from PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, datetime

I'm trying to export some data in Excel, but when I format my date column, it doesn't change and excel doesn't recognize as a date.

How can be done fo that date be recognized by Excel?

Here's my PowerShell command to get the attributes of files:

```
 $ITEMS=@(ls -path $STARTFOLDER -Recurse |Select FullName,Name,Attributes,@{Name="Date"; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}},Extension,@{Name="Mbytes";Expression={"{0:N3}" -f ($_.Length / 1Mb)}})
```

And an example of the data

`FullName      : C:\file.txt
Name          : Computers.txt
Attributes    : Archive
LastWriteTime : 05.08.2015 08:35:15
Extension     : .txt
Mbytes        : 0.002`

Comment: I've tried to convert it to `[datetime]` but it doesn't work

Comment: What is your actual question? How is that object array getting to Excel?

Comment: @arco444 i've edited the question

Comment: How are you getting the data *into* excel? i.e. are you outputting to a csv? Using an Excel COMObject?

Comment: Which file you need to delete ? The file under the fullname or name in your csv?

Comment: I don't need to delete the file, just to get the informations

Comment: I use `add-content` to put the array in the file because there are a lot of files after I import the txt in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to declare `'$_.LastWriteTime'` as `[datetime]` object?
Try this:

```
select @{l="Date";e={$_.LastWriteTime -as [datetime]}}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is when i export my CSV in Excel, the field Date is not recognized as a Date field.